# How to get the value of custom HTML attribute using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a repeater with check boxes in each row. I'm trying to check the check box in row based on another check box in same row. For this I'm executing a function on OnClick event of check box and this function finds the custom attribute of the parent and checks if parent is checked or not. If returned true it checks the check box with same attribute name for child class . Th problem is I can't get the value of custom attribute of parent class. It is always undefined.

childid in jquery function is always undefined. I tried  using data property too but it's of no use .

```
$(objid).data('chldname');
function check_view(objid) {
    var childid = $(objid).attr('chldname');
    if ($(objid).is(':checked')) {
        $("[name=" + childid + "]").attr('checked', true);
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<td style="text-align: center">
    <asp:checkbox id="cb_uploadaccess" runat="server" chldname='chld<%#Eval("ROLE_SEQ")%>' onclick='JavaScript:return check_view(this);' />
    <asp:hiddenfield id="hiddenuploadaccess" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("UPLOAD_ACCESS")%>' />

</td>
<td style="text-align: center">
    <asp:checkbox id="cb_viewaccess" name='chld<%#Eval("ROLE_SEQ")%>' runat="server" />
    <asp:hiddenfield id="hiddenviewaccess" runat="server" value='<%#Eval("VIEW_ACCESS")%>' />

</td>
```

Comment: Please share your generated HTML for better understanding

Comment: What you have listed as HTML is actually ASP code

Comment: @KaushikThanki `<asp:CheckBox>` basically comes out as `<input type="checkbox" runat="server" chldname="chld" onclick="Javascript: return check_view(this);" />`

Comment: I think the actual problem is I can't see my custom attributes in the list of attributes for this object..I mean I can't see chldname in attributes list

Comment: Since data attribute is becoming more widely accepted it might be better to switch to `data-childname`. I know you've said you have tried it but I would go that route and work on solving the problem using `data-`.

Comment: If you change to `.data('chldname')` you have to change your asp/html to `data-chldname="chld<%#Eval("ROLE_SEQ")%>"` as well. If you inspect your code does the element have any data inside `chldname`?

Comment: <asp:CheckBox ID="cb_uploadaccess" runat="server"  data-chldname='chld<%#Eval("ROLE_SEQ")%>' onclick='JavaScript:return check_view(this);' />

Comment: No what is the actual output that it produces on the page? If it is rendering and Eval isn't producing any actual data then your javascript will always find undefined.

Comment: as I mentioned earlier I can't see my attribute in attribute list of objid..there  is no chldname in attribute list when I debug

Comment: Then it seems like asp isn't writing out the attribute. Try assigning it using InputAttribute in your code behind on your object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this in another way, just changed my JQuery function like this which worked.

```
function check_view(objid)
            {
                var childid = $(objid).attr('ID');
                var childId1 = childid.substr(childid.length - 2);



                if ($(objid).is(':checked')) {

                        $(childId1).attr('checked', true);
                        $("[id$=chpMain_rptDocAccessroles_cb_viewaccess" + childId1 + "]").attr('checked', true);

                }

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create data-chldname attribute and access using

```
$(objid).attr('data-chldname')
```

Answer (score 0):

use javascript to get the attribute

```
 objid.getAttribute('chldname');
```

Comment: How is that different from using jQuery?

Comment: you are not  passing jquey object

Comment: No but they are passing a reference to the element that was clicked which is being used as a jQuery selector: `$(objid).attr('chldname');`

Comment: we need to see the output html for understand the exact problem

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me.

```
$("#cb_uploadaccess").attr('chldname');
```

This returns the proper answer. Are you perhaps passing the ID string instead of the whole jQuery object when starting the function or something?